# Updata data based on the status django model

Tags: python, django

I am currently creating a model and one of the field is the percentage. I wanted to update the percentage field depending on the status.

this is my models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('NY','Not Yet'),
        ('RN','Running'),
        ('CO','Completed'),
    )


    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, default='NY')
    percentage = models.FloatField()

    if status == 'CO':
         percentage = 100
    else:
         percentage = 0
```

and this does not work or does not save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override Model's save method and put your logic in there.

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('NY','Not Yet'),
        ('RN','Running'),
        ('CO','Completed'),
    )


    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, default='NY')
    percentage = models.FloatField()


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status == 'CO':
            self.percentage = 100
        else:
            self.percentage = 0
        super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Comment: In the `save` method, `status` should be `self.status` and `percentage` should be `self.percentage`

Comment: Oh Yes @Nick, Thanks :). Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I'd been looking for

Comment: Can I use different name of the method because `def save(self)` has a conflict with other methods that I have

Comment: You are overriding the `save()` method of the model and there can be only one `save()` method of a `Model`. Where is the conflict ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just using the `percentage` field for display purposes, you don't need to make it a real field. I would do it like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('NY','Not Yet'),
        ('RN','Running'),
        ('CO','Completed'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS, default='NY')

    @property
    def percentage(self):
        if self.status == 'CO':
            return 100
        else:
            return 0
```

But if you really do want it to be a field, you could do something like what Kapil Sachdev's answer has.

Comment: This is great. but for this I'll use Kapil Sachdev's answer however your answer is very much helpful for my other problem. Thank you so much